# How do I extract links from HTML with a Perl regex?

Tags: html, regex, perl

I have a HUGE html which has many things I don't need, but inside it has URLs that are provided in the following format:

```
<a href="http://www.retailmenot.com/" class=l
```

I'm trying to extract the URLs... I tried, to no avail:

```
open(FILE,"<","HTML.htm") or die "$!";
my @str = <FILE>;

my @matches = grep { m/a href="(.+?") class=l/ } @str
```

Any idea on how to match this?

Comment: @soulSurfer2010 - did you get a specific error?  Or just unexpected behaviour (and if so, what)?

Comment: Maybe you just have a typo there; it says `"(.+?")` when it should be `"(.+?)"`

Comment: I tried, still no go...I dont get an error.

Comment: I test it with grep, it sometimes i cathes the correct ones, and sometimes its still too greedy

Comment: for example, this is a greeey one: a href="http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:SY0IFA33Tg0J:www.coolsavings.com/+coupons&amp;cd=5&amp;hl=en&amp;ct=clnk" onmousedown="return clk(this.href,'','','','5','','0CCwQIDAE')">Cached</a> - <a href="/search?hl=en&amp;rlz=1B5GGGL_enIL302IL302&amp;q=related:www.coolsavings.com/+coupons&amp;tbo=1&amp;sa=X&amp;ei=dTadTJOGOtvNjAeg0qWODQ&amp;ved=0CC0QHzAE">Similar</a></span></span></div><!--n--><!--m--><li class=g><h3 class="r"><a href="http://www.mycoupons.com/" class=l

Comment: tried it with : grep -iP --color=auto 'a href="(.+?)"\sclass=l  FILE.TXT

Comment: @soulSurfer2010, please edit your revisions and what you tried (the two comments previous to this one) *into the question* (hit the 'edit' link below the tags.) It looks better formatted properly, and far easier to read and work with.

Comment: Why hasn't anybody linked to this classic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags ?

Comment: What Yuji says: just don't do it this way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [HTML::SimpleLinkExtor](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-SimpleLinkExtor), [HTML::LinkExtor](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-Parser), or one of the other link extracting Perl modules. You don't need a regex at all.

Here's a short example. You don't have to subclass. You just have to tell `%HTML::Tagset::linkElements` which attributes to collect:

```
#!perl
use HTML::LinkExtor;

$HTML::Tagset::linkElements{'a'} = [ qw( href class ) ];

$p = HTML::LinkExtor->new;
$p->parse( do { local $/; <> } );

my @links = grep { 
    my( $tag, %hash ) = @$_;
    no warnings 'uninitialized';
    $hash{class} eq 'foo';
    } $p->links;
```

If you need to collect URLs for any other tags, you make similar adjustments.

If you'd rather have a callback routine, that's not so hard either. You can watch the links as the parser runs into them:

```
use HTML::LinkExtor;

$HTML::Tagset::linkElements{'a'} = [ qw( href class ) ];

my @links;
my $callback = sub {
    my( $tag, %hash ) = @_;
    no warnings 'uninitialized';
    push @links, $hash{href} if $hash{class} eq 'foo';
    };

my $p = HTML::LinkExtor->new( $callback );
$p->parse( do { local $/; <DATA> } );
```

Comment: Great module, but seems like I dont only need the hrefs but , hrefs that have 'class=l ' after the link...

Comment: HTML::LinkExtor can help you figure out what other attributes are set.

Comment: @brian d foy, HTML::LinkExtor only collects attributes that are URLs.  It doesn't collect the `class` attribute.  You'd have to subclass it to ignore links with the wrong `class`.

Comment: Sorry that I didn't have time earlier to produce an example. No need for a subclass.

Comment: "You don't need a regex at all." And you should not use a regex at all. It has been said that if any phrase ought to be emblazoned on the top of SO, "you cannot use regular expressions to parse XML" is certainly one of them.

Comment: amazing!! amazing!! and again! amazing! Thanks a lot!