# Regular expression in HTML

Tags: regex, perl

Going crazy over here, trying to fetch html-links from an html sourcefile.
What am I missing? I've tested the regular expression it works fine, but here it returns nothing at all (tried different websites as well)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use LWP::Simple;
my $url = "http://www.svenskaspel.se";
my $content = get($url);
my @links = ();

$content =~ /<a[^>]* href=([^"]*)/;
push (@links, $_);

foreach $_ (@links){
    print "$_\n";

    }
```

Comment: remove the single quotes which was around `<a`

Comment: Tried it, same problem, nothing..

Comment: [Don't use regex for this](http://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/), get a proper parser like [HTML::TreeBuilder::LibXML](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::TreeBuilder::LibXML)

Comment: Please consider bookmarking the [Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496) for future reference. And yes, [do not use regex to parse html](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454)

Comment: what do you expect the output to be from that script?

Comment: Use a parser, but keep in mind that XML and HTML are different things.

Answer (score 2):

Seriously  - don't. HTML parsing via regex is a dirty hack, and creates brittle code. [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Here's an example of some alternative approaches:
[How do I extract links from HTML with a Perl regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791897/how-do-i-extract-links-from-html-with-a-perl-regex)

Comment: What happened to closing duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

The lines:

```
$content =~ /<a[^>]* href=([^"]*)/;
push (@links, $_);
```

must be:

```
$content =~ /<a[^>]* href="([^"]*)/;
push (@links, $1);
```

Comment: Still not working, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex seems incorrect.

check this link - http://regexr.com/3ajeh to see the working regular expression. paste source of any HTML page in text area to test.

Please note that regular expression is not a suggested way of parsing HTML as HTML is not a regular language.

See [this famous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Answer (score 0):

Unless the HTML file is extraordinarily simple (a list of links) you should probably avoid parsing it yourself as has been mentioned. In this answer I'll suggest that you can "cheat" and install something from CPAN to help :-)

*e.g.* you could [`use Mojolicious`](https://www.metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious) - specifically the `mojo` tool that is included with that module:

```
mojo get https://www.svenskaspel.se a attr href
```

which in "long form" is something like:

```
perl -Mojo -E ' my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new; 
      say $ua->get("https://www.svenskaspel.se")
     ->res->dom->find("a[href]")->map(attr => 'href')->join("\n");'
```

The longer one-liner outputs:

```
/
/
/spela
/mina-spel


/bomben
#
/stryktipset/tipssm
/triss
/grasroten
/spelkoll
/kundservice
/om-cookies
```

which includes blank lines because some of the `href` attributes have no content (`href=""`).

You can control the selector using the matching syntax from [`Mojo::DOM` SELECTORS](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojo/DOM/CSS#SELECTORS).  That way, similar to DOM CSS selectors, something like: `...->dom->find("a[href^=/]")` would look for values of  `href` attributes that begin with `"/"`.